# Assigning a list element with the sum of the other elements

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I have a 2d matrix which can be any size but always a square. I want to loop through the matrix and for each diagonal element (`x` in the example) I want to assign the value `1-sum_of_all_other_values_in_the_row` e.g.

```
Mtx = [[ x ,.2 , 0 ,.2,.2]
       [ 0 , x ,.4 ,.2,.2]
       [.2 ,.2 , x , 0, 0]
       [ 0 , 0 ,.2 , x,.2]
       [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0, x]]

for i in enumerate(Mtx):
    for j in enumerate(Mtx):
        if Mtx[i][j] == 'x'
            Mtx[i][j] = 1-sum of all other [j]'s in the row
```

I can't figure out how to get the sum of the j's in each row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i,row in enumerate(Mtx): #same thing as `for i in range(len(Mtx)):`
    Mtx[i][i]=0
    Mtx[i][i]=1-sum(Mtx[i])

    ##could also use (if it makes more sense to you):
    #row[i]=0
    #Mtx[i][i]=1-sum(row)
```

Comment: @DSM -- Yup.  Sometimes I get focused on the "difficult" part of the problem and forget the little details.  Thanks.

Comment: Come to think of it, you're not really using `row`, either;  clearly you could, though.  Now we're bikeshedding. :^)

Comment: Perfect it works great thank you for the great answer. Is the `_` a python built in 'trick'?

Comment: @adohertyd `_` is just a variable name.

Comment: @adohertyd -- nested loop completely unnecessary :).

Comment: @adohertyd -- I'm playing around with this to try to figure out the most clear way to say it.  I dislike `range(len(...))`.  `_` is just a variable name which is often used to mean "I need this to unpack the values, but I'm not going to use it".  I switched back to `row` because in comments I made a version which uses `row`.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as such:

```
from copy import copy
for i, row in enumerate(Mtx):
    row_copy = copy(row)
    row_copy.pop(i)
    row[i] = 1 - sum(row_copy)
```

Comment: Right, I re-read your code, my comment was wrong.  I'll delete.

Comment: Thanks badzil but I think the other answers are a little easier.

Comment: You can also get rid of the dependence on `copy` with `row_copy=row[:]`.  Just for future reference.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- Originally I thought you were right too, but his solution is OK since he's popping out of the copied row, not the row he's assigning into.

Comment: @badzil: Your code is correct. My apologies for an incorrect bug report. Deleting it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
mtx = [[ 0 ,.2 , 0 ,.2,.2],
       [ 0 , 0 , .4 ,.2,.2,],
       [.2 ,.2 , 0 , 0, 0],
       [ 0 , 0 ,.2 , 0,.2],
       [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0, 0]]
for i in range(len(mtx)):
    summ=sum(mtx[i])
    mtx[i][i]=round(1-summ,2) #use round to get 0.4 instead of .39999999999999999
print(mtx)
```

**output:**

```
[[0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.2], [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2], [0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Nothing in the question mentions that x == 0.

Comment: @mgilson I can assign 0 to begin with instead of x. Thanks Ashwini you always provide good answers to my questions.